# How does wall climbing work?

Tags: bunny-must-die

Wall jumping is an unlockable ability that allows you to, well, jump off walls you're facing towards. As far as I understand you need to jump up to the wall, depress the jump button, press it again and no matter how long that second press is you jump quite a few ways off the wall. I can't seem to be able to climb any height with it.

...except [you *can* wall-jump.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=3BUO7TmJwE0#t=600s) What gives? Has it changed in the new localized version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is move toward the wall (the one you're facing when you bounce) after jumping. The simplest thing to do is just repeatedly press over (facing the wall) and the jump button and you should easily be able to climb walls.

I'm sure there's something more to it than "spam both buttons" but I do recall that working. I'll try and figure how the more logical aspect of it tonight.

Comment: Just a random trivial note about this - it should be noted that doing this will change the wall jump into a somersault animation (whereas a normal wall jump leaves you in a normal jump state). There isn't a lot of points where this is relevant, since wall climbing largely avoids any stomp opportunities, but just something to recall. It's also a way to shift to somersault state while wall kicking at all.